# Convert Date String Using Date-FNS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, date-fns

I would like to convert this string `2022-06-01T14:42:52+00:00` using date-fns.
The problem is that its outputting `Invalid time value`

**Code**

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'

let deadlineDate = '2022-06-01T14:42:52+00:00'

console.log(format(deadlineDate, `yyyy-LL-dd`))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string to the *format* function. You should pass the `Date` object to the *format* function.

You can parse the string using `parseISO` function and then pass it to `format`

```
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns"

let deadlineDate = parseISO('2022-06-01T14:42:52+00:00')

console.log(format(deadlineDate, `yyyy-LL-dd`))

// "2022-06-01"
```

Reference: https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/parseISO

Comment: Thank you. Can you do this in one line?

Comment: Yeah, you can ( `format(parseISO('2022-06-01T14:42:52+00:00'), `yyyy-LL-dd`)` )